# why does tsc dump the "extends ..." part of the following Typescript class when compiling to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc, transpiler

why does tsc dump the "implements ..." part of the following Typescript class when compiling to JavaScript ?

tsc version: Version 4.6.2 / Node version: v17.4.0

compilation command:

```
tsc -t es6 test.ts
```

// test.ts

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement implements HTMLDivElement {
    align: string;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.align = "center";
    }
    public connectedCallback(): void {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        this.style.width = "100px";
        this.style.height = "100px";
    }
}

window.customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);

const myElement = document.createElement("my-element");
const Content = document.createTextNode("My text!");
myElement.appendChild(Content);
// connectedCallback is called when appended to another element
document.body.appendChild(myElement);
```

// test.js

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.align = "center";
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        this.style.width = "200px";
        this.style.height = "100px";
    }
}
window.customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
const myElement = document.createElement("my-element");
const Content = document.createTextNode("my text!");
myElement.appendChild(Content);
// connectedCallback is called when appended to another element
document.body.appendChild(myElement);
```

Comment: Typescript drops everything about types (except vanilla JS stuff like `extends`) when it compiles, and I'd guess that the `implements` stuff is Typescript type stuff which gets dropped.

Comment: Because `implements` is not valid JavaScript? It's only a type annotation, and gets dropped like any other type declarations (`: string`, `: void`, `public`).

Comment: Here is a good introductory tutorial about custom elements / web components / html templates / shadow dom :

https://youtu.be/PCWaFLy3VUo

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the workaround is as follows:

```
class MyElement extends HTMLDivElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.style.width = "100px";
        this.style.height = "500px";
        this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}

customElements.define('my-element', MyElement, {extends: 'div'});

const myElement = new MyElement();

const Content = document.createTextNode("my text!");
myElement.appendChild(Content);

// connectedCallback is called when appended to another element
document.body.appendChild(myElement);
```